# Displaying an image from database

Tags: mysql, image

I realize that this is probably going to be a duplicate question, but I have searched and searched for an answer and am unable to find the right answer.  I want to display an image uploaded to my database on a web page. I have tried about a zillion different ways and just can't get it. I would hard code it, but I'm using a "base" page for all the pages so all the information is shown dynamically. I hope this makes sense. I just don't know how to make the image show up? Is this a more than one step process?  I'm still fairly new to all this, so it has quite confused me.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you using PHP? You basically have to use a scripting language to retrieve the image from the database and send it back to the browser. That script should be in the `src` of your image tag. E.g. `<img src="get_image.php?id=1">`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a page displays text, this is what happens

1. A URL ie `https://audaxing.wordpress.com/2013/05/20/600km-stage-by-stage/` does a request to a web server
2. The server sends back a header saying "here comes some html text"
3. The server finds the appropriate content
4. the server sends back the text with the content, in html format

For an image

1. A URL ie `http://audaxing.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/img_20130518_194100.jpg?w=500&h=375` does a request to a web server
2. The server sends back a header saying "here comes an image" including the image format type
3. The server finds the appropriate content, which will be binary data in a image format such as jpeg
4. The server sends the binary data back

So all you have to do is send an appropriate header, select the data for the image from the database and then "print" the data like you would a page.  You may need to use a special binary mode for the data printing

The exact details depend on the platform (php, scala play, django etc etc) that you are using